# Quartz trigger is not firing with JobStoreTX

Tags: java, sql-server, quartz-scheduler

I'm creating my first scheduled task in Quartz. For my project I need to store the data in the database.

For starting the scheduler I use:

```
scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
scheduler.start();
```

I created a simple job for testing the scheduling

```
package com.atlascopco.framework.schedule.jobs;

import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

public class StoredProcedureJob implements Job {

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {


        System.out.println("test"); 

    }

}
```

In my database I created some record manually.
JOB_DETAILS

```
SCHED_NAME  JOB_NAME    JOB_GROUP   DESCRIPTION JOB_CLASS_NAME  IS_DURABLE  IS_NONCONCURRENT    IS_UPDATE_DATA  REQUESTS_RECOVERY   JOB_DATA
test    test    test    test    com.atlascopco.framework.schedule.jobs.StoredProcedureJob   1   1   1   1   NULL
```

TRIGGERS

```
SCHED_NAME  TRIGGER_NAME    TRIGGER_GROUP   JOB_NAME    JOB_GROUP   DESCRIPTION NEXT_FIRE_TIME  PREV_FIRE_TIME  PRIORITY    TRIGGER_STATE   TRIGGER_TYPE    START_TIME  END_TIME    CALENDAR_NAME   MISFIRE_INSTR   JOB_DATA
test    test    test    test    test    test    1477559872000   NULL    NULL    WAITING SIMPLE  1477559872000   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

SIMPLE_TRIGGERS

```
SCHED_NAME  TRIGGER_NAME    TRIGGER_GROUP   REPEAT_COUNT    REPEAT_INTERVAL TIMES_TRIGGERED
test    test    test    10  1000    0
```

Now when I start my application the scheduler start. On regular time the log of the scheduler is adding new lines (no error only debug messages). What do I wrong to start the job?

Also when I'm doing `scheduler.getTriggerGroupNames()`the list is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to save the jobs in the database using the API of Quartz

```
JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(StoredProcedureJob.class)
                    .withIdentity("dataJob", "dataJobGroup")
                    .storeDurably(true)
                    .requestRecovery(true)
                    .build();

            SimpleTrigger trigger = (SimpleTrigger) newTrigger()
                    .withIdentity("trigger1", "dataJobGroup")
                     .startNow()
                    .withSchedule(
                            simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(1)
                                    .repeatForever()).build();

            scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
```